# Auto copy data files

Tags: folder-redirection

I would like to use Dropbox to backup some data files which cannot reside in the Dropbox folder. However, I do not want to have to manually copy the files each day. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/661171/syncing-folders-outside-dropbox-using-symbolic-links-and-junctions

Answer (score 0):

`mklink /J "C:\Dropbox\backups" "C:\Users\user\Documents\important files"`
First path is the folder pointing at the folder currently residing at the second path.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ tells a bit more. I would scroll down to the command line instructions so that you do not have to install anything extra.